# How do I create an apple script that changes the destination folder of airdropped files?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, finder

I've downloaded the following apple script, which moves airdropped files to a specified folder (which I'll refer to as the Airdrop folder):

```
property AIRDROP_FOLDER : "Macintosh HD:Users:pschorn:Airdrop"
property QUARANTINE_KEY : "59"

property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START : "ls -l -@ '"
property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END : "' | tr '\\n' ' ' | sed 's/.*com\\.apple\\.quarantine\\s*\\(\\d*\\)/ \\1/' | awk '{$1=$1};1'"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with i from 1 to length of added_items
        set current_item to item i of added_items
        set quarantine_type to getQuarantineType(POSIX path of current_item)
        if quarantine_type is equal to QUARANTINE_KEY then
            moveFile(current_item, alias AIRDROP_FOLDER)
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on moveFile(move_file, destination_dir)
    tell application "Finder"
        move move_file to destination_dir with replacing
    end tell
end moveFile

on getQuarantineType(file_path)
    return do shell script GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START & file_path & GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END
end getQuarantineType
```

I followed the instructions on this [website](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/03/03/change-airdrop-destination-folder-mac/) to set it up as a folder actions script.

**However, if I move an airdropped file out of my newly created airdrop folder and back into my downloads folder, it gets automatically put BACK in the airdrop folder.** I don't want this to happen.

I found that after applying this terminal command `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine [file path of airdropped file]`, the file will no longer get moved back into my airdrop folder after I move it out.

**MY question is: How do I integrate this command into the above apple script so that the airdropped files do not automatically get moved back to my airdrop folder after I move them out of it?**

One way to do this might be to set up another folder action script that removes the quarantine attribute from all files that are placed into my airdrop folder using the aforementioned terminal command.

EDIT: **HERE IS THE SOLUTION!!!** CREDIT: @Oantby

```
property AIRDROP_FOLDER : "Macintosh HD:Users:pschorn:Airdrop"
property QUARANTINE_KEY : "59"

property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START : "ls -l -@ '"
property GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END : "' | tr '\\n' ' ' | sed 's/.*com\\.apple\\.quarantine\\s*\\(\\d*\\)/ \\1/' | awk '{$1=$1};1'"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    repeat with i from 1 to length of added_items
        set current_item to item i of added_items
        set quarantine_type to getQuarantineType(POSIX path of current_item)
        if quarantine_type is equal to QUARANTINE_KEY then
            clearQuarantineFlag(POSIX path of current_item)
            moveFile(current_item, alias AIRDROP_FOLDER)
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on moveFile(move_file, destination_dir)
    tell application "Finder"
        move move_file to destination_dir with replacing
    end tell
end moveFile

on getQuarantineType(file_path)
    return do shell script GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_START & file_path & GET_QUARANTINE_COMMAND_END
end getQuarantineType

on clearQuarantineFlag(file_path)
    do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine '" & file_path & "'"
end clearQuarantineFlag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you're just looking to get that line into the script?

at the end, I'd probably add:

```
on clearQuarantineFlag(file_path)
    do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine '" & file_path & "'"
end clearQuarantineFlag
```

and then add `clearQuarantineFlag(POSIX path of current_item)` *right* before `moveFile(current_item, alias AIRDROP_FOLDER)`.

<sub>Disclaimer: I wrote this based on what's there already, and haven't used much AppleScript in a while</sub>